# color whole row cells text

Tags: python, xlwt

I am using individual cells to color the text

```
worksheet.write(1, 1, "This is a row 1, column 1", xlwt.easyxf("font: color blue;"))
worksheet.write(1, 2, "This is a row 1, column 2", xlwt.easyxf("font: color blue;"))
worksheet.write(1, 3, "This is a row 1, column 3", xlwt.easyxf("font: color blue;"))
```

Can it be done so that a single operation could change the whole color of the text of the row.

Comment: No, but you could make it into a loop.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean you want to change your statements in a loop:

```
for index in xrange(1, 4):
    worksheet.write(1, index, "This is a row 1, column %d" % index,
     xlwt.easyxf("font: color blue;"))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for col in range(1,4):
    worksheet.write(1, col, "This is a row 1, column "+str(col), xlwt.easyxf("font: color blue;"))
```